# How to clickEvent or fireEvent on a image by their class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs

Would I be able to click a image based on their class? Example in jquery would be `$(.imageID).click()`;

```
<img src="picture.png" class="imageClass">
```

How would I click event or fire event that in EXT JS 5+ ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ext, but it seems to have a `select()` you can use to select by CSS selectors, so `Ext.select('.imageClass').on('click', function() { }); ` maybe?

Comment: How did you register the event listener in the first place? "Simulating a click" should just be a matter of calling the same functions (maybe with its expected arguments).

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.select('.imageClass').each(function(item){
     item.fireEvent('click', item); 
});
```

should fire a click event on every element of class `.imageClass`

Comment: @VKid Apologies, used the wrong selector - see my edit

Comment: TypeError: me.hasListeners is undefined, what if that image as an itemID ? can i find it by the itemID?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Ext.select()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-event-select) to get the behavior you're after.

```js
Ext.select('.pic').on('click', function() { alert('Mew!'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/ext-all.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" class="pic" />
```

Comment: I want to simulate a click, not manually clicking and getting the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Firing UI events programmatically is very, very bad practice, unless you are testing the application. So if you are not testing, just call the handler directly and do not simulate clicks this way.

Comment: I see. Have you considered to try [Bryntum Siesta](http://www.bryntum.com/products/siesta/) for testing?

Comment: I've used test studio, but their recorder doesn't catch the recorded click on this particular image click event. that's why i want to try and simulate the click itself.

Comment: Siesta is testing for Ext written in Ext so it should be able to test all aspects of the application. I used it briefly some time ago and it was satisfying at that time.

Comment: I just need this clickevent on this image. Everything else i can test already.

Comment: See this fiddle I've just coded: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lpl Hope it helps.

Comment: it works, but only for firefox/chrome browser, not IE11 ? I believe it clicked the image, but the image i have is suppose to fire event within that click.

Comment: What is IE? ..... kidding. Sorry, I cannot help you any further. I'm a Mac user so I cannot run IE. Try to consult MS forums.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76071/discussion-between-v-kid-and-saki).

Comment: Try to give the image role="button" if it changes anything

Comment: the image does have a role="button"